# Adding new feature not working in pysandbox

Tags: python, pysandbox

I am using the [pysandbox](https://github.com/vstinner/pysandbox) to run the Python code in sandbox environment. I got it up and running, but I want it to support python `datetime` module. As per the documentation, I added 'datetime' in the config as follows,

```
sandbox = SandboxConfig('datetime', cpython_restricted=False)
```

but if I run the code I still get the error,

**'global name datetime is not defined'**

Comment: This works for me with pysandbox version 1.5.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using the same version 1.5.1. Did you do any additional configuration apart from adding 'datetime' to the config? In my case, I had to modify the SandboxConfig to enable 'traceback' for pysandbox to get the path of 'datetime' module. It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: All I did was create a new virtualenv, run `pip install pysandbox`, and then do `from sandbox import SandboxConfig; sandbox = SandboxConfig('datetime', cpython_restricted=False)`. I'm using Python 2.7. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks! I did a deep dive into this issue and figured out that my global imports are not available inside any function. `import datetime def get_today(): print(datetime.date.today())` gives **global name datetime is not defined** error. But if I pass datetime as an argument to the function only then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue with the pysandbox. Looks like you are passing some parameter to the sandboxed function through the `locals` variable. In this case, the import is not added to the global namespace.

Simply write `global datetime` right after you import it and it will work. Otherwise, you may also pass it as a function parameter.